# arithmetic progression of primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that there is no arithmetic progression that consists *only* of primes.

A question that I've been set; I'm guessing it makes use of primes being written in the form 4k+1 and 4k+3? Not sure where to start.

Thanks.

Comment: Play with some special cases.  Can you find an arithmetic progression of primes with common difference 1?  Why not?  What about 2?  3?  Can you find an argument that generalizes to any common difference d?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An arithmetic progression is a sequence of the form
$$a,\quad a+b,\quad a+2b,\quad a+3b,\quad a+4b,\quad\ldots, a+nb,\quad\ldots$$
with $b\neq 0$.

If $a$ is not prime, you're done. So suppose $a$ is a prime. Can you find a term later in the sequence that is *guaranteed* to be a multiple of $a$?

Comment: Thank you, I should have noticed this. A bit too late in the evening to be doing any of this.

Comment: it is not true that a should be prime. a must be odd. 21 is an odd and not prime. 21+2 = 23 is prime. so 21+2k, k=0,1,2,3... contain primes.